# using pgeocode lib of python to find the latitude and longitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, latitude-longitude

why am I getting NaN in the answer when i run the following code. it works fine for some pin codes and doesnt for others.

```
import pgeocode
nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('in')
print(nomi.query_postal_code("302023"))
```

the answer i am getting is :

```
postal_code       302023  country code         NaN  place_name          NaN  state_name           NaN  state_code           NaN  county_name          NaN  county_code          NaN  community_name       NaN  community_code       NaN  latitude             NaN  longitude            NaN  accuracy            NaN  Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

For pgeocode to work, it is essential to download a text file containing the postal codes from the specific country of interest.

Head over to http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/ and download the zip postal code lookup file of the country you are looking for (ie. IN.zip for India, GB.zip for United Kingdom).

Unzip the downloaded file and place the new folder inside the same folder where code file is located.

The code you have should be working after that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `pgeocode` but I usually use `geopandas` to get coordinates:

```
import geopandas

df = geopandas.tools.geocode(302023)

# get lat and lon
df['lon'] = df['geometry'].x
df['lat'] = df['geometry'].y

print(df)

                    geometry               address        lon       lat
0  POINT (75.77929 26.95578)  302023, India, India  75.779289  26.95578
```

Here is the [geopandas documentation](http://geopandas.org/geocoding.html)

Comment: i am unable to download the geopandas library . following are the errors:                            ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\INDIA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5oeux3wh\fiona\

Comment: check out the [install documentation](http://geopandas.org/install.html) but if you use anaconda your can just `conda install geopandas` if using pip make sure all the dependencies are installed.

Comment: i downloaded all the dependencies .. now gthe error is:                          GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out

Comment: That will sometimes happen as its default api for geocoding is free. You can read the usage docs [here](https://geocode.farm/geocoding/free-api-documentation/) on the free api: "Free Users Have 250 Per Day Limit and 4 Requests Per Second Limit (IP Based)" If you are geocoding a list of pin codes then you will need to use a `while-loop` with a `try` and `except` statement. Or you can use Google's geocoding api. it is all in the documentation I listed in my answer. Please read the docs.